# Break out of outer function if condition in inner function fails

Tags: python, return, break

I have a function `move()` with long ass code which takes over a minute to run and during this time the condition to execute the function might no longer be true. At first I was looking for something to check if the statement was true before executing each new line of code but apperantly that doesn't exist (super strange).

My new idea was the following:

```
def breakk():
    if x==0 or y == 0 or z == 0:
        code
        code
        code
        return 

def move():
    if x==1 and y == 1 and z == 1: 
        code
        code
        breakk()
        code
        code
        breakk()
        code
```

But this doesn't work since the `return` in the inner function `breakk()` has no effect on the outer function `move()`

My current work around is just terrible.. :

```
breakkk=0
def breakk():
    global breakkk
    if x==0 or y == 0 or z == 0:
        code
        code
        code
        breakkk=1
         

def move():
    global breakkk
    if x==1 and y == 1 and z == 1: 
        code
        code
        breakk()
        if breakkk==1:
            breakkk=0
            return
        code
        code
        breakk()
        if breakkk==1:
            breakkk=0
            return
        code
        .....

move()
```

Comment: I dont understand the problem fully well, but why not just return a boolean in your `breakk` function, then just use `if breakk(): return`? I would also advise avoiding global variables, just pass the variables as arguments in your `breakk` function. Something like... `if breakk(x, y, z): return`.

Comment: Another possibility is to raise an exception, if it makes sense to.  By raising an exception you can "break out of" any function no matter how deeply nested its call is, but then you will have to add the appropriate exception handling code at whatever level you want the exception to stop bubbling up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the `breakk()` return a `boolean` and then check whether `breakk()` is `true`:

```
def move():
    if x==1 and y == 1 and z == 1: 
        code
        code
        if breakk():
            return
        code
        code
        if breakk():
            return
        code
```